# Typo3 Banner Image Rotation for Newsletters

Tags: plugins, rotation, typo3, banner, newsletter

i work with Typo3 for integrating AdImages (Banners) in Newsletters. We want to get more banner-image rotation in our Newsletters, cause now if we put in a new Banner, the old one is not getting showed. 
Is there a possobility to import like 5 Banners and let them roatate automatically, to that each time a newsletter is send, the Banner image changes?
I saw some Plugins, put most of them are for Websites and i don´t think they will work on newsletters as well.

Regards,
Chris

Comment: so I think your problem has no simple solution, please be more specific: what kind of image rotation should appear? 1. after each newsletter campaign (=all recipients get the same image for one specific newsletter, but the next newsletter will have another image) 2.the image will rotate for each send mail (recipient1 gets image1, recipient2 gets image2, ...recipient6 gets image1, ...). 3. each NL-campaign gets a random image (teh same for all recipients) 4. each time a recipient opens the NL it gets a random image

Comment: Thanks for your answer Bernd!
i want to make it the first way, every recipient should get the same image and the next NL should get another image. (1. after each newsletter campaign (=all recipients get the same image for one specific newsletter, but the next newsletter will have another image)

Comment: and if they open they´r newsletter a few days later, the image sould be still shown...

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your newsletter system you could manage the image rotation by a plugin which selects the image based on a variable. this variable needs to be updated after/for each newsletter campaign.

The dependencies is how often the image(plugin) is called. if a cache is involved it might work from start, but you might need to implement a more complex condition to change to next image.

If you have a counter for the newsletter which is accessible in typoscript you might even dispense the plugin as you can calculate 'newsletter-number modulo 5' to get the image. (keywords: split, listNum, prioriCalc)

Otherwise you need to decide when a newsletter is send or will be send and trigger an incrementation of a global index value (modulo 5).